# resolver sistemas de ecuaciones diferenciales con parámetros desconocidos en python

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

Tengo un sistema de ecuaciones diferenciales lineales acopladas de primer orden en las cuales tengo dos parámetros desconocidos. Este es el sistema:

- dR/dt=k2*Y(t)-k1*R(t)*L(t)+k4*X(t)-k3*R(t)*I(t)
- dL/dt=k2*Y(t)-k1*R(t)*L(t)
- dI/dt=k4*X(t)-k3*R(t)*I(t)
- dX/dt=k1*R(t)*L(t)-k2*Y(t)
- dY/dt=k3*R(t)*I(t)-k4*X(t)

Los valores iniciales son X(0)=0, Y(0)=0, R(0)=N, L(0)=0, I(0)=0. En cuanto a las constantes, k1 y k2 son constantes conocidas y k3, k4 las que debo encontrar. Tengo una serie de datos de tiempo y de Y(t) para esos tiempos.

Mi idea era resolver el sistema usando sympy y luego hacer una regresión no lineal de los datos para la solución Y(t) del sistema. Sin embargo, sympy no puede resolverlo. Aquí el código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy 
from sympy.solvers.ode.systems import dsolve_system
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from scipy.integrate import odeint

k1 = sympy.Symbol('k1', real=True, positive=True)
k2 = sympy.Symbol('k2', real=True, positive=True)
k3 = sympy.Symbol('k3', real=True, positive=True)
k4 = sympy.Symbol('k4', real=True, positive=True)
t = sympy.Symbol('t',real=True, positive=True)
L = sympy.Function('L')
R = sympy.Function('R')
I = sympy.Function('I')
Y = sympy.Function('Y')
X = sympy.Function('X')

f1=k2*Y(t)-k1*R(t)*L(t)+k4*X(t)-k3*R(t)*I(t)
f2=k2*Y(t)-k1*R(t)*L(t)
f3=k4*X(t)-k3*R(t)*I(t)
f4=-f2
f5=-f3

eq1=sympy.Eq(sympy.Derivative(R(t),t),f1)
eq2=sympy.Eq(sympy.Derivative(L(t),t),f2)
eq3=sympy.Eq(sympy.Derivative(I(t),t),f3)
eq4=sympy.Eq(sympy.Derivative(Y(t),t),f4)
eq5=sympy.Eq(sympy.Derivative(X(t),t),f5)

Sys=(eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5])
solsys=dsolve_system(eqs=Sys,funcs=[X(t),Y(t),R(t),L(t),I(t)], t=t, ics={Y(0):0, X(0):0})
```

Y la respuesta:

```
NotImplementedError: 
The system of ODEs passed cannot be solved by dsolve_system.
```

Lo siguiente sería usar un método numérico como runge-kutta, pero no sé cómo hacerlo cuando hay dos parámetros desconocidos.

He intentado otro tipo de abordajes usando la librería gekko, pero no entiendo bien como funciona y no obtengo los resultados esperados. Éste es el código de éste intento:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import sympy

nt=101
m.time=np.linspace(0,240,nt)

#Parametros a optimizar
k3=m.MV(value=1e8,ub=6e9,lb=0)
k3.STATUS=1
k4=m.MV(value=0.01, lb=0)
k4.STATUS=1

#Parámetros conocidos
k1=m.Const(value=6500, name='k1')
k2=m.Const(value=0.9,name='k2')
N=m.Const(value=100,name='N')

#variables
y=m.Var(value=0, name='y')
x=m.Var(value=0,name='x')
l=m.Var(value=0,name='l')
i=m.Var(value=0,name='i')
r=m.Var(value=N,name='r')

p=np.zeros(nt)
p[-1]=-1.0
final=m.Param(value=p)
m.Obj(-y*final)

#equations
m.Equation([x.dt()==-k4*x+k3*r*i,y.dt()==-k2*y+k1*r*l,r.dt()==k2*y-k1*r*l+k4*x-k3*r*i,l.dt()==k2*y-k1*r*l,i.dt()==k4*x-k3*r*i])

m.options.IMODE=6
m.solve()

print('Objective: '+str(y[-1]))
print(k3,k4)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(m.time,y.value,label='y')
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,label='x')
plt.plot(m.time,r.value,label='r')
plt.plot(m.time,l.value,label='l')
plt.plot(m.time,i.value,label='i')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Y la respuesta:

```
Objective: -2.3503950759e-22
p1 p2
```

[![Gráfica de las variables con gekko][1]][1]

Otro intento lo he hecho con pysindy, pero no lo conozco y no consigo implementarlo bien.

¿Alguien sabe cómo abordar esto?
Muchas gracias